# Concat string in javascript gives message as NAN

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to bind a value to a `string` like in the way below, but on the screen it's giving the message as `Nan`.

```
'<div style="height: 40px; padding: 0px 0;">
     <p>
         <span>' + txtCapital +' </span>
     </p>
     <p>
         <span>'+ txtRole/txtFund +'</span>
     </p>
</div>'
```

this is giving me the output as below:

```
 CapitalOne 
   NAN
```

whereas I should get the output as:

```
  CapitalOne
  PHD/DEPT
```

Comment: `....txtRole + '/' + txtFund...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, in ur code its actually trying to do arithmatic operation `/` so its resulting `NAN`, but what u need is just treat `/` as a string, bound it with `single quotation` and concatination operators `+`

`<div style="height: 40px; padding: 0px 0;"><p><span>' + txtCapital +' </span></p><p><span>'+ txtRole+'/'+txtFund +'</span></p></div>`

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to divide strings. The division operator needs to be wrapped in quotes to be treated as a string. Change it to:

```
txtRole + "/" + txtFund
```